# Caesar Cipher in html using javascript (with ASCII codes) help required

Tags: javascript, python, html, scripting, interactive

I'm having trouble getting this code to work. Am more familiar with python - new to javascript. This was what my python equivalent looked like:

```
   userinput = input("Enter the message you want to encryppt: ")
   shift = int(input("How many letters do you want to shift by? "))
   empty = ""

   for char in userinput:
   a = ord('a') if char.islower() else ord('A')
   if char.isalpha():
    firstord = ord(char) - a
    realord = firstord + shift
    realord = realord % 26
    realord = realord + a
    alpha = (chr(realord))
    empty = empty + alpha
   else:
    notalpha = ("?")
    empty = empty + notalpha
  print(empty)
```

and below is the javascript version  - I've used comments. I've set it up a bit differently as well. (the last block is the html) For some reason, it's only showing the button and input boxes - but the output is not being displayed.

Thanks for the help

```js
<script> 

function enterName(){


 var userName = document.getElementById("word_in").value;        //get the input string from the page
 var shiftBy = Number(document.getElementById("shift").value); //get the  amount of shift and convert it into a number. This Is IMPORTANT
 var size= userName.length;          //get the size of the input string
 var encrypt="";
 var temp = 0;
 var i=0;
 
 //step through the string 1 character at a time
 for (i=0; i<size; i++){
 
 //store the ASCII value of each character
  temp=userName.charCodeAt(i){

  // Uppercase
  if ((temp >= 65) && (temp <= 90)){
   temp = (((temp - 65 + shiftBy) % 26) + 65);
  }

  // Lowercase
  else if ((temp >= 97) && (temp <= 122)){
   temp = (((temp - 97 + shiftBy) % 26) + 97);
  }

  else {
   temp = "?";
  }
   
  }
  encrypt += String.fromCharCode(temp) 
 } 
  
 //output to the page
 document.getElementById("word_out").innerHTML = encrypt;

}

</script>
```

```html
<body>
<p>Please enter your name:</p>
<input id="word_in">
<p>Please enter the shift:</p>
<input id = "shift">
<button type = "button" onclick="enterName()"></button>
<p id = "word_out"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have one open curly bracket and one closing curly bracket too much. See comment.

```js
function enterName() {
    var userName = document.getElementById("word_in").value;        //get the input string from the page
    var shiftBy = Number(document.getElementById("shift").value);   //get the  amount of shift and convert it into a number. This Is IMPORTANT
    var size = userName.length;                                     //get the size of the input string
    var encrypt = "";
    var temp = 0;
    var i = 0;

    //step through the string 1 character at a time
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        //store the ASCII value of each character
        temp = userName.charCodeAt(i); //{ <------------------------------------ too much

        // Uppercase
        if ((temp >= 65) && (temp <= 90)) {
            temp = (((temp - 65 + shiftBy) % 26) + 65);
        }

            // Lowercase
        else if ((temp >= 97) && (temp <= 122)) {
            temp = (((temp - 97 + shiftBy) % 26) + 97);
        }

        else {
            temp = "?";
        }

        //} <------------------------------------------------------------------- too much
        encrypt += String.fromCharCode(temp);
    }

    //output to the page
    document.getElementById("word_out").innerHTML = encrypt;
}
```

```html
<p>Please enter your name:</p>
<input id="word_in">
<p>Please enter the shift:</p>
<input id="shift">
<button type="button" onclick="enterName()"></button>
<p id="word_out"></p>
```

Comment: Thought it might be something simple like that - thank you

Answer (score 0):

I created a working example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/w4rafn1j/2/

The following line needs a semicolon after it instead of a block, because it is a function call:

```
temp=userName.charCodeAt(i);
```